# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 - I cant figure out why the code is running out of bounds

Tags: java, project, indexoutofboundsexception

i am getting the error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
This is a 2 part program. a service file, and a client file. (for a school project)

```
public String[][]gameBoard(int rows, int columns)
{

    for (rows = 0; rows<gameBoard[0].length; rows++)
    {

       for (columns = 0; columns<gameBoard[0].length; columns++)
       {
          gameBoard[rows][columns]=""; //initializes the values of the string array (gets rid of null)
          System.out.print(gameBoard[rows][columns]+"_ ");
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
    return gameBoard;
 }
```

Is the part that is getting the error, (making and printing a board, based on user input).

is how i am calling it in the client file.
How or what is causing this to go out of bounds?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the gameboard array declared...?

Comment: And why does your method take (require) a row and column argument if you just use these to iterate through the loop and immediately set them to 0?

Comment: you have an incomplete sentence here :

"is how i am calling it in the client file."

suggesting there's something we can't see...

Comment: And I bet `rows<gameBoard[0].length` should be `rows<gameBoard.length`, the columns comparation seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you have initialized the 2D array correctly,

My Guess would be that your loops for row and column traversal is a little off...

In your code the first loop traverses the columns and so does the inner loop..

You need to traverse columns for each row.

I would try

```
for (rows = 0; rows<gameBoard.length; rows++)
{

   for (columns = 0; columns<gameBoard[rows].length; columns++)
   {
      gameBoard[rows][columns]=""; //initializes the values of the string array (gets rid of null)
      System.out.print(gameBoard[rows][columns]+"_ ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
return gameBoard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature indicated that you will return a thing of type `String[][]`, and that your method is called `gameBoard`. You're using this `gameBoard` as if it was an array, but there is no array called `gameBoard` at all.

I will not give you the source code just yet, as I do not want to do your homework, but I can tell you as much, that you need to create a new local `String[][]` inside the method body. It should be just as big as the row and columns you ask for as the method's parameters, and should be call something appropriate (like `gameArr`).

Next up, your for-loops are slightly off. Use the parameters instead of the wrongly used method name - that's what they're here for, right? ;)

Lastly return your newly created local array.

Comment: The array must be declared in a snippet which is not shown, otherwise the compiler would refuse to compile this code.

Comment: @Mauren: If that's the case, then the logic in the code is completely off, and he shouldn't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at index 0.

Comment: this is probably the case.

Comment: @Izmaki
Hey  Thanks a bunch!
Sorry for the incomplete question, kind of new to stack over flow. The "formatting" in asking the question was kind of weird to me.

I got it to work, As you said, i created the local String gameBoard[][]= new String[rows][columns];.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure at this point the line with gameBoard[0] is uninitialized.

Initialize gameBoard[] before trying to access [0].

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/java-use-arrays-with-two-dimensions-or-more.html

Comment: He will probably see a NPE if he had not initialized the array